# Is there a way to do this conditional JOIN without a second query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages` m
JOIN questions q ON m.question_response = q.question_id 
WHERE m.message_id = '$message_id'
```

Problem is that the JOIN isn't always needed, it's only needed if the value of `m.question_response` isn't `0`. Is there a way to do the JOIN on that condition without resorting to a second query?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can join on multiple conditions, and they are allowed to be static.

```
SELECT *
FROM `messages` m
JOIN questions q 
    ON m.question_response = q.question_id 
    AND m.question_response <> 0
WHERE m.message_id = '$message_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM `messages` m,`questions` q 
WHERE m.message_id = '$message_id' 
   AND m.question_response = 0 
   OR (m.question_response <> 0 AND m.question_response = q.question_id)
```